# Linear Algebra: Proof explanation, quotient spaces, null space, subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $E$ be a vector space and let $M$ be a subspace of $E$. Prove that if $\phi : E \to F$ is linear, then the following assertions are equivalent:

- $M \subseteq \ker \phi$.
- There exists $\psi : E/M \to F$ such that for all $x \in E$, we have $\phi(x) = \psi([x])$.

**Perhaps I am not understanding this question quite right. I have provided the proof below, and my confusions with this problem here:**

- Why do we take $x - y \in M$? What does that have to do with $E/M$ and
  $\psi$?
- Why is getting $[x]$ to be a singleton important? Why do we then denote, because it is a singleton, $x$ by $\psi[x]$? And why does this prove 2?
- Why is  $\phi(x) = \psi([x]) = \psi([0]) = 0 $ true? The first equality is by
  definition, but then why is $0$ introduced and why is $\psi[0] = 0$,
  why $\psi$ is not known to be linear- or is that implied by the
  assumption of 2?

---

Proof:

Assume $M \subseteq \ker \phi$. For all $x \in E$ we have $\psi[x] = \{\phi(y) : y \in E, x − y \in M\}$.

If $x − y \in M$ then $x − y \in \ker \phi$ since $M \subseteq \ker \phi$, and so $\phi(x) = \phi(x − y + y) = \phi(y) + \phi(x − y) = \phi(y)$ so $\psi[x]$ is a singleton, whose only element we denote by $\psi[x]$. This proves (2).

Assume (2). Let $x \in M$. We have $\phi(x) = \psi([x]) = \psi([0]) = 0$ so $x \in \ker \phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $x-y \in M$, we have that $[x] = [y] =E/M$ by definition. And you are proving that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$.
- The set $[x]$ can't be a singleton unless $M = \{ 0 \}$. But you prove that $\phi([x]) = \{ \phi(x + m) | m \in M\}$ is a singleton so you can uniquely assign a vector to $\phi([x])$.
- Because $x \in M$ we have $[x] = [0]$.

Are you sure you understand the definition of $E/M$, it seems most of your misunderstanding comes from there.